# How to get SharedPreference from a class extending from Fragment?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, adt

I am new in android development. In my first app i was using SharedPreferences to share some strings in whole app. Now i am making and app using tabs. My first Activity is LoginActivity where i am setting SharedPreferences:

```
 myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

 SharedPreferences.Editor e = myPrefs.edit();
 e.putString("name", "Piscean");
 e.commit();

 Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TabActivity.class);
 startActivity(mainIntent);
```

TabActivity is extending from FragmentActivity and it has four Framents. Now i want to access SharedPreferences in one of the Fragment of TabActivity. 
I tried to use

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
 System.out.println("Name: "+myPrefs.getString("name", "empty"));
```

and its printing out empty. Any idea how can i do that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)`

Comment: sorry i did not mention that. i used it but its always giving default value. for example  SharedPreferences myPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0);
     
     System.out.println("Name: "+myPrefs.getString("name", "empty")); is always printing out empty. And i set it as Piscean in an activity before

Comment: @Piscean edit your question and post the code you used to store and retrieve values from shared preferences

Comment: the snippet is correct. Is it the actual code ? Maybe you misspled some String ?

Comment: it is actual code. that code is copy paste. did not miss anything

Comment: how could it be ? SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
 System.out.println("Name: "+myPrefs.getString("name", "empty"));

you get prefs and use myPrefs

Comment: I changed getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);  to this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0); and cleaned project. restarted eclipse and now its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your context has changed from an Activity to a Fragment.  I assume in your Activity you were using:

```
this.getSharedPreferences(..)
```

In your fragment, you need your container activity's context:

```
getActivity().getSharedPreferences(...)
```